# Plugin for autolink keywords and SEO

Tags: seo, wordpress

There are many plugins for Wordpress which allows to replace the first occurrence of some keyword with the link to a specific webpage.

Is this a good practice or can be penalizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds bad to me. If you let wordpress control your keywords and replace them with links, especially if the links have keywords, then it might be terrible for SEO. Regardless what you use to make your website, make sure your links go to relevant pages on your site. Don't let wordpress create links solely on keywords that direct you to a site that has so much emphasis on that keyword that the relation to your site is practically nothing.

For example, if you have a website about apples and your keyword is apple, and you had wordpress turn the word "apple" into a link to another site with the anchor text as "apple", then you need to double check that site, because if its low quality or very unrelated, then you're in trouble. For example, if you talk about the creation of apples and you link to a definition page for apples yet you don't mention that the link is pointing to the  definition, then you're in deep trouble.

So what I would do if I were you is test the pages before putting them live.